# C++ ifstream help (simple)

Tags: c++, file, input

I am trying to get some names from a .txt file and add them on a char array but something weird happens. Here's my input portion of the code:

```
int main()
{
string namelist[30];
int i=0;
string line;
ifstream file("C:\\names.txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    while ( getline (file,line).good () )
    {
        getline(file,line);
        cout << line << endl;  // It prints the names normally (it was added for   debugging) //
        namelist[i] = line;
    }
    file.close();
}
cout << namelist;  // Here is the prob.
```

On the last line of the code it prints a pointer on the console and not the list and I
have no clue why.
I'm pretty new to c++ so don't be rude!

The text file is something like:

```
John
Nick
Samatha
Joe
...
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the name of array it's a pointer, write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    std::cout << namelist[i] << std::endl;
```

or

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//...
std::copy(namelist
         , namelist + 30
         , std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n")
);
```

Comment: why? it doesn't have an * in its definition like: char * namelist[30];

Comment: ok thanks. you mean I should read more abour strings. i suppose that we can't use them as lists, like chars right?

Comment: An array is an implied pointer.  It reserves a block of memory large enough to contain the requested number of some datatype and provides a pointer to the first element.  When you index the array with (`namelist[i]`) it's much the same as doing pointer arithmetic (`*(namelist + i)`).  The bottom line is that an array of `string` objects is in fact used as a `string*`.  The string datatype is just a class with a few members.  The character data itself is allocated dynamically and pointed to by the class.  The string objects in your array are the same size regardless of what strings you assign.

Comment: @Makis Renieris, std::string it's a container(of chars) which can be dynamicly resize, at the 3-rd line you declare array of std::string, in other words it's a two dimensional array of chars with fixed count of rows(30)

Comment: oooh i think i got it thank you very much for your answer. I have learned some Python some months ago and I had it all really simple in my mind... (with Python's lists) I 've a lot to learn about datatypes in c++.